# Open authenticed Wordpress page from mobile app

Tags: authentication

I have mobile app that uses Worpdress JWT Token Plugin API to login. It uses WP users to authenticate to the app. The token is used for other WP API calls. Now I need to open up authenticated page from mobile app and I need to pass authentication data of some kind so the user don't have to login once again. What options are ?

Answer (score 0):

Most often a Bearer token is sent in the request headers. Add the `Authorization` header with a value of `Bearer ${authToken}` (note the space between `Bearer` and `${authToken}` variable). The plugin should verify the token automatically on each request.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I don't need to call API I just need to open up specific page and pass authorization data (token ?). Right now if I use token get from /wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token and pass it to GET example-url.com/example-page as Authorization Bearer ... It returns Login page. I don't know if it matters but I use Force Login plugin to restrict access to the site for not-logged in users.